# PHP Live Output from a passthru with Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, exec, command-line-interface

I am building some CLI process with PHP+Zend (Yeah i hate it too) and I'm having a weird issue which I don't know how to fix regarding the output of the exec() or passthru() commands.

In a nutshell I have a *testexecAction* which does

```
fwrite(STDOUT,"First\n");
passthru("ping -c 3 192.168.18.10");
fwrite(STDOUT,"Second\n");
```

and when I call it using a CLI interface I made for Zend, i get the following output

```
~ php console.php --funcion testexec
First
Second
PING 192.168.18.10 (192.168.18.10): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.18.10: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.692 ms
...
```

As you see, the output from the passthru command its being printed, but its printed AFTER the "Second" line, like its being saved in some buffer somewhere, I would like to change this behavior so the output isnt buffered, but I have no idea how to acomplish it.
The reasoning behind it its that I am using passthru/exec to call other long php process which I want to see the output real time and in order

My guess its that its a Zend option somewhere, but I'm not sure about the "somewhere", as I have made other tests using raw PHP and the output its not buffered but printed straightaway to the console.

My Zend CLI interface its fairly simple

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] = "/console/" . getConsoleArg("-function");
$application->bootstrap()
    ->run();
```

Comment: Why don't you use `system` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it calling ob_flush(); on my inner process output.